# How to Delete Application folder in Javascript/Html Metro App for windows

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

```
 var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
var path = applicationData.localFolder.path;
path = path.replace('\\LocalState', '');



var folder = Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.getFolderFromPathAsync(path).done(function () {

});
folder.deleteAsync().done(function () { });

window.close();
```

Executing the code i get the exception that im not allowed to access hidden folder and i have to change the file attribute of it. Please suggest me a solution. Please note that i want to delete entire application folder and not just application data.

Comment: What is your goal in doing this? The application data folder will be removed when the user uninstalls the app. The app should only need to manage its data within the folder, not the folder itself. As you're finding, the app won't have full access to the folder.

Comment: The thing is that i want to add a functionality which wipes out the application data and settings. The settings folder does not get deleted. Is there a way to clear out all local and roaming settings.

Comment: Well, since it is your app and you know every saved you could iterate over and delete every single one of them, am I right?